# Can loadInitial() be blocking when loading data from API

Tags: android, android-paging

How to use [loadInitial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PageKeyedDataSource.html#loadInitial(android.arch.paging.PageKeyedDataSource.LoadInitialParams%3CKey%3E,%20android.arch.paging.PageKeyedDataSource.LoadInitialCallback%3CKey,%20Value%3E)) in the paging library?

I am wondering If I could use a blocking call in `loadInitial()` to get the response from API. By doing this, I can make sure the returned pagedList contains the first page. Is it the correct way to use this method?

```
pagedListAdapter.submitList(list)
```

[In Google's example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/7f861fd45d158e6277a3c35163c7f663e135b2cf/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/repository/inMemory/byPage/PageKeyedSubredditDataSource.kt#L110), they are using loadInitial() in a blocking way. Is it considering a good practice?

Comment: yes, you can use your blocking api here

Answer (score 2):

No.  That's why it contains a callback parameter-  so you can call it back when done.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/7f861fd45d158e6277a3c35163c7f663e135b2cf/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/repository/inMemory/byPage/PageKeyedSubredditDataSource.kt#L110  In Google's example, they did used loadInitial() in a blocking way.  Do you know any reason for that?

Comment: Probably because it leads to simpler example code when it doesn't need to deal with threads and threading.  To be clear-  you definitely can do it synchronously, and there's some applications that may make sense (if lookup is quick).  But it isn't necessary, and I wouldn't use it if it wasn't fast to do.

Comment: I know the thead used in `loadInitial()` is not UI thread, but I am not so confident I can do it synchronously in terms of network requesting. worrying any side effect about it.

Comment: @Cody yes, it is called in the background thread and you dont have to create another one (or use some kind of async api that makes it under the hood)